# Next App Router: How call API with CORS from client component

Tags: next.js, next.js14

I'm working in a project based on Next App Router and I'm facing problems when trying to call API services with CORS policies actives.

The point is, in brief, I have a server component called page.tsx that loads a child component type client that contains a button to make a request to an API with CORS. So I'm not being able to perform this request from the child component.

The only successful request should be done from parent component type server, but this way is not possible to link the request to a click user interaction with the button.

**Code:**

Parent component (server component):

```
import AvatarSignout from '@/app/components/AvatarSignout/AvatarSignout';

export default async function Home() {
  // component logic here

  return (
    <>
      <AvatarSignout />
      {/* more components here */}
    </>
  );
};
```

Child component (client component):

```
'use client'

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

import Button from '@/app/components/Button/Button';
import {MoviesClient} from '@/app/api/client';

function AvatarSignout() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [showSignoutButton, setShowSignoutButton] = useState(false);

  async function handleSignout() {
    const signoutRes = await MoviesClient.signout() // CORS error
    if(signoutRes) {
      setShowSignoutButton(false)
      router.push('/login');
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div
        onMouseEnter={() => setShowSignoutButton(true)}
      ></div>
      {showSignoutButton && (
        <Button
          text='Sign out'
          variant='primary'
          onClick={handleSignout}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default AvatarSignout;
```

This is the signout client function:

```
async signout() {
    const res = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/auth/sign-out`, generateRequestOptions({method: 'GET', auth: true}))
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
    }
    return res.json()
  },
```

What could I do to succeed on this API service request protected with CORS?

Thank you in advance!